# How to repair corrupt MS Excel (XLS and XLSX) Files

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have important MS Excel file data and unfortunately got corrupt due to virus attacks, so my crucial Excel sheet got lost, How to repair corrupt MS Excel (XLS and XLSX) Files. If have any solution please assist me.

Comment: This is not a file recovery service, so please [edit] your question to tell us what have you researched or attempted so far. Have you tried to restore a copy of the file from backup? It's also helpful to know what version of Excel you are using.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to repair a corrupted Excel file](http://superuser.com/questions/285141/how-to-repair-a-corrupted-excel-file)

Answer (score 1):

A corrupt Excel spreadsheet can be repaired by using the *Open and Repair* technique. It is a built-in repair function that opens a corrupt Excel file forcefully.

- Open MS Excel, press Ctrl+O, then locate the corrupt Excel spreadsheet and select it.
- Click on the arrow shown besides the Open button, select *Open and Repair*.

It will take just a few seconds to be completed and the selected file will be opened, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

When I have had an Office file that the original Office application can't open, I've used [LibreOffice](http://www.libreoffice.org) to open it, and had a fair success rate at it.  Once opened, you can re-save as a new Excel document (taking care not to overwrite the original, in case this doesn't repair your file properly) and then opening that file in Excel.

Comment: It would improve your answer greatly if you elaborate on how you did it. We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer: please explain why you're recommending it as a solution.